# crash at start - InstantiationException

Tags: android, appcompatactivity

I have an Android app in Google Play. And in the developer console I see quite a few crashes in the onCreate of MainActivity of the app.

I have never seen this crash myself. Only in Google play.

I don't really have a clue what the problem is, or in which direction to search for a solution.

The complete stacktrace is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2984)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3045)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1642)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1518)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:431)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate (Fragment.java:102)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState (FragmentManager.java:1952)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState (FragmentController.java:144)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java:307)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate (AppCompatActivity.java:58)
  at be.gps.android73.activities.LanguageActivity.onCreate (LanguageActivity.java:23)
  at be.gps.android73.activities.main.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:117)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6956)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1126)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2927)
```

The lines in these class that are pointing to some of my code are

```
at be.gps.android73.activities.LanguageActivity.onCreate (LanguageActivity.java:23)
at be.gps.android73.activities.main.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:117)
```

MainActivity is the main activty of the app which shows a bunch of different fragments. And it extends LanguageActivity. LanguageActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity

The onCreate of MainActivity looks like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //this is line 117 from the stacktrace
   ...
```

And LanguageActivity looks like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //this is line 23 from the stacktrace
   ...
```

Anyone any clues or tips what can be causing this ?

Comment: The error message suggests that there is no empty constructor for a Fragment.You MUST have an empty public constructor for your Fragments

Comment: That was indeed de problem in 1 of my fragments.

Now I can simulate the crash (by using the "Don’t keep activities" setting) I can see the crash log in LogCat.

In LogCat however, I have the very convenient extra information : java.lang.InstantiationException:NameOfTheClass has no zero argument constructor


Do you have any idea how to display this extra information in the Google Play Developer console ? As you can see in my post this extra info is missing from the stacktrace. This is not the first time that I note that GooglePlay stacktraces are missing some info...

Comment: I don't use that feature in Google Play. I prefer Crashlytics. It has a ton of features and I think it is also free. It takes 5 mins to add it to your project.